# How to add dropdown arrow under caret in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css

I am using the Bootstrap 4 dropdown option.

I wanted to add an up arrow for the dropdown menu in the top left.

In Bootstrap 3, we have a caret markup on the button, so we can add the arrow to the dropdown menu.

But in Bootstrap 4, we don't have a caret markup, using the `dropdown-toggle` class only caret is added.

How can we add arrow to dropdown menu here?

I added the Bootstrap 3 example link:

https://www.bootply.com/QD8FO89DcY

The same functionality is needed in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it, preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 11):

In Bootstrap 4 it has been removed, add that caret/arrow by yourself, please have a look at the below working snippet, where I have added it with a custom CSS.

```css
.dropdown-menu-arrow {
  top: -25px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-menu-arrow:before,
.dropdown-menu-arrow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 7px 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  z-index: 1001;
}
.dropdown-menu-arrow:after {
  bottom: -18px;
  right: -8px;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
.dropdown-menu-arrow:before {
  bottom: -17px;
  right: -8px;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button id="customDropdown" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="customDropdown">
      <span class="dropdown-menu-arrow"></span>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .dropdown-menu-arrow--right {
  left: 90%;
}
.dropdown-menu-arrow--left {
  right: 10%;
} for some helpful class modifiers

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```css
.dropdown-menu::before {
    border-bottom: 9px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-left: 9px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 9px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    left: 5%; /* position */
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
}

.dropdown-menu::after {
    border-bottom: 8px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-left: 9px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 9px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    left: 5%; /* position */
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button id="customDropdown" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="customDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
/* for shadow */
.dropdown-menu::before {
    border-bottom: 9px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-left: 9px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 9px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    left: 5%; /* position */
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
}

.dropdown-menu::after {
    border-bottom: 8px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-left: 9px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 9px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    left: 5%; /* position */
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you guys posting the exact same answer 3 times?