# Bootstrap version 4.x.x, auto direction carets when popper change dropdown placement

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to make Bootstrap version 4.x.x version just like the previous 3 version, how change "caret" direction if the dropdown placement of the dropdown menu changes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add dropdown arrow under caret in Bootstrap 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52623337/how-to-add-dropdown-arrow-under-caret-in-bootstrap-4)

Comment: This question is the direction arrow above the dropdown menu. I mentioned, **"Caret"** in the dropdown menu button.

Comment: There is only one possible glyph involved, you can call it arrow or caret, potatoes potatos ...You could try the extreme hard effort it is to give an example of what you mean, if you really believe there is potential for confusion.